# Is it appropriate to return HTTP 503 in response to a database deadlock?

Tags: rest, database-deadlocks, http-status-code-503

Is it appropriate for a server to return `503 ("Service Unavailable")` when the requested operation resulted in a database deadlock?

Here is my reasoning:

- Initially I tried avoiding database deadlocks, but I ran across https://stackoverflow.com/a/112256/14731
- Next, I tried repeating the request on the server-side, but I ran across [Java Servlets: How to repeat an HTTP request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16620003/14731). Technically speaking I can buffer the request entity but scalability will suffer and clients are more likely to see `503 Service Unavailable` anyway.

Seeing as:

- It's easier to ask clients to repeat the operation.
- They need to be able to handle `503 Service Unavailable` anyway.
- Database deadlocks are rather rare.

I'm leaning towards this solution. What do you think?

**UPDATE**: I think returning `503 ("Service Unavailable")` is still acceptable if you wish it, but I no longer think it is technically required. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17960047/14731.

Comment: Even if you program this in production you may still end up with timeout, which would cause your load balancing proxy to send 504 to client.

Comment: @agilevic, what do you mean? Are you saying I need to ensure deadlock-by-timeout is configured to use a small timeout value to avoid `HTTP 504`?

Comment: Database deadlocks can last longer than load balancer's timeout thus blocking the response. If you are capable of detecting a deadlock before that timeout you can respond to client with 503 - a sensible choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's fine so long as the entire transaction is rolled back or if the request is idempotent.

Answer (score 2):

I think semantically 409 Conflict is a better alternative - basically if you have a deadlock there's contention for some resource, and so the operation could not be completed.

Now depending on the reason for the deadlock, the request may not succeed if submitted a second time, but that's true for anything.

For a 503, as a client I'd implement some sort of back-away/circuit breaker operation as the system is rate limited, whereas 409 relates to the specific request.

Answer (score 1):

Just got here with the same question and no clear answer on the issue.

- a 503 is acceptable but might not be correctly interpreted
- a 409 is also OK but in my case was not OK (since multiple resources could end up returning a this error for the same URL)

In my case I ended up returning a 307 redirect on the same URL.

Clients will automatically "retry" and the second call works because the resource is only raising a deadlock during its initial creation.

Be warned **that might end up in an infinite loop**